# How to send complete POST to Model in Code Igniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, post, model

What would be the best way to send a complete post to a model in Code Igniter? Methods I know are as follow:

Name form elements as array, eg.

```
<input type="text" name="contact[name]">
<input type="text" name="contact[surname]">
```

and then use:

```
$this->Model_name->add_contact($this->input->post('contact'));
```

The other would be to add each element to an array and then send it to the model as such:

```
<input type="text" name="name">
<input type="text" name="surname">
```

and

```
$contact_array = array('name' => $this->input->post('name'),
                       'surname' => $this->input->post('surname'));
$this->Model_name->add_contact($contact_array);
```

Which one of these would be best practice, and is there a way to directly send a whole POST to a model (or a whole form maybe?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply pass $_POST variable to method that you want to work with all POST variables. I see your concern, but rest assured: $_POST is sanitized by security filtering function whenever controller is instantiated.

So:

```
$this->Model_name->add_contact($_POST);
```

Comment: Ah great! Didn't know that $_POST itself was sanitized. Thanks!

Comment: Well, it is, to some extent, but to be sure, you can enable auto-xss filtering in config.php by setting $config['global_xss_filtering'] = TRUE

Comment: $config['global_xss_filtering'] is enabled, it just never occurred to me that it sanitized the actual $_POST var.

Comment: BEWARE: From code ignite doc (https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/models.html): Note: For the sake of simplicity in this example we're using $_POST directly. This is generally bad practice, and a more common approach would be to use the Input Class $this->input->post('title')

Comment: @Leandro Hey, keep in mind that I answered this question 4 years ago, I am pretty sure that back then this was an accepted practice. :) However, points to you for pointing that out. Cheers.